# Task.FromResult on GetAll with a filter and awaiting it - bad practice?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am looking for a way to make GetAll async on the application with a filter and not block the users till this loads:

Here is what I have done so far;

This is a generic method in  my dbrepository.

```
public Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
{
    return Task.FromResult(filter != null ? dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter) : dbContext.Set<TEntity>());
}
```

Then I call the generic dbrepository in my crud manager

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntityDto>> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
{
    return (await repository.GetAll(filter)).Select(i => mapper.Map<TEntityDto>(i)).ToList();
}
```

I have read this article that it is a bad practice to await Task.FromResult as it only adds overhead to the state machine.

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/should-i-await-on-task-fromresult-method-calls

What I understand is that I need to make this sync but then if the users are waiting for this to load it will block them.

How do I handle this?

Comment: Does your first GetAll() really need to return a Task? Because of deferred execution, the function isn't actually doing any processing, it is simply forming a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make your methods appear async when they actually aren't.

Nothing in your dbrepository `GetAll` method is asynchronous; you are just wrapping a synchronous operation in a `Task` unnecessarily.

If users are concerned about blocking, it should be their decision to run the method call in a separate thread.